# Android RatingBar stars with shadow/glow

Tags: android, shadow, ratingbar

I want to add a shadow to the stars in a RatingBar. I also want to use half-stars, so I can't just add the shadow directly on the star image. Is this possible to achieve or will I have to create a custom RatingBar?

I make non-filled stars transparent using the following drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another rating bar behind the original one and make its style as an shadow. Then sync the behind rating bar with the one in top.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:focusable="false" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then sync the the rating bars. As any one changed the other will change too.

Comment: I want to be able to use half-stars `android:stepSize="0.5"`, so I'm quite sure this won't work.

Comment: I'm sure it will work or i am not understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I understand your solution now. I unfortunately also want some blur on the shadow though.

Comment: I want the same effect as `android:shadowRadius` has on text. It creates a blurred/soft shadow. Your solution will create a sharp edge on the shadow-ratingBar's half-stars which makes soft shadows impossible.

Comment: What about giving a custom style to the background rating star and set some soft pictures for it !!! ???

Comment: Again, this won't work for half-stars. Here is an image to illustrate how the shadow would be cut: http://i.imgur.com/C396fPh.png

Comment: If you mean that the right side of the half star will be sharp you are completely correct.